# how to make an "either or" enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate

I would like to format a dichotomy in the following way:

> Let blah blah blah blah....
>
> Then either one has
>
> (I) case A
>
> or (II) case B

I would like the numbers (1) and (2) aligned as in an `enumerate` environment, with a slight indent to the right so that the "or" sits to the left of (2). Many thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you going to use this format a lot of times or only once?

Comment: Anyway, `\item[or (II)] case B` should work.

Comment: Nice idea thanks! Unfortunately this method leaves the "or" sticking out a bit into the margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution using the `enumitem` package. I define a new `enumerate` counter style `\dicho` which prints either "(I)" or an "or" before larger numbers. Then, I define a new list type `dichotomy` with this style and some extra margin to not have the "or" stick out of the page. This also works with more than two cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\def\dicho#1{\expandafter\@dicho\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@dicho#1{\ifnum#1>1 or \else\fi(\@Roman#1)}
\makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter{\dicho}{\@dicho}{or (III)}
\newlist{dichotomy}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[dichotomy]{label=\dicho*,leftmargin=1.5cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1] Then either one has
\begin{dichotomy}
\item case A
\item case B
\end{dichotomy}

\end{document}
```

[image]